# how do i allocate available ram in windows to command prompt?

Tags: windows, cmd

when i am running crfsuite(http://www.chokkan.org/software/crfsuite/) in command prompt to make a model by giving training, it gets closed with error number:998 which is caused because of insufficient memory. how can i allocate all my free RAM to command prompt?

Comment: This has nothing to do with cmd. You need to let crfsuite have access to more memory. See the crfsuite documentation or ask their support how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do as a (developer oriented) end-user is to modify the binary to enable [`large address aware`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z.aspx) mode (assuming it isn't already set).

```
editbin.exe /LARGEADDRESSAWARE [path to crfsuite exe]
```

This can allow the OS to make more memory available to the process.

Answer (score 0):

This is 32 bit figures.

Every program has access to 4GB of memory. 2GB for it's own code and data, and 2GB for system libraries.

Assuming you haven't configured Windows' memory then every program will have 4GB.

Often out of memory means it could not allocate contigious memory in the amount requested.

Always check for files for corruption when this happens, else run a 64 bit version.

Comment: Note that there are some differences if you are running on a 32 vs 64 bit OS, and whether or not /LARGEADDRESSAWARE is enabled. This page has a [nice chart](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=889654) showing when and how much a process gets under different scenarios.